# Does Catel work well with a WPF Navigation application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

I am working on a large WPF application where the entire UI is based around Pages rather than Windows.

`The application is 50% MVVM / 50% MVCB (Model View Code Behind)`

So, I am planning to migrate it all to MVVM and I am evaluating Catel as a framework.  The current hand-built framework that controls the MVVM isn't bad but doesn't add much productivity value. Given the large amount of work involved in converting > 100 screens I want to save a lot of repetitive work and make it nice and consistent, hence I am evaluating frameworks.

I think it will take me a while to understand Catel, so I am wondering if the fact the application uses Pages is a showstopper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catel does support page navigation (same for Silverlight, Windows Phone and WinRT). Note though that is a rarely used feature inside Catel (and WPF at all).

You can use the INavigationService instead of the IUIVisualizerService to navigate between your pages.

Comment: Where you say that page navigation is rarely used in WPF, are you talking about System.Windows.Controls.Page and System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationWindow?  If so, how do you know?

Comment: I know that because of the number of questions I receive about it (nearly zero).

Comment: Does the plural of anecdote = data?